# Importing python packages

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pypi

If I am looking at this package on pypi https://pypi.org/project/shamir-mnemonic/, how do I know what the module is called when I import it into my python code after I have installed it with pip3? I am not interested in using it with CLI

Answer (score 2):

The first point to start would be the official documentation. If there is none, then check your `site-packages` directory to see if there is a folder there that seems related to the package. In your case, we can find a folder called `shamir_mnemonic` and indeed

```
python -c "import shamir_mnemonic"
```

suceeds.

If available, you can also look at the source code of the module